# Generic methods set value for T

Tags: c#, generics

Can you help me I'm new to generic methods. I've been searching for an answer but can't find one hope you can help.
I've tried boxing and unboxing but it errors.
Here's my code.

```
            if (input == 1)
        {
            Sum sum = new Sum();
            InputTwoDegits<Sum>(out firstNumber, out secondNumber, out firstNumberChecker, out secondNumberChecker, input, sum);
            factoryClass = sum;
            factoryClass.Compute();
        }
        else if (input == 2)
        {
            Difference dif = new Difference();
            InputTwoDegits<Difference>(out firstNumber, out secondNumber, out firstNumberChecker, out secondNumberChecker, input, dif);
            factoryClass = dif;
            factoryClass.Compute();
        }

    private static void InputTwoDegits<T>(out int firstNumber, out int secondNumber, out bool firstNumberChecker, out bool secondNumberChecker, int input, T returnClass) where T : class
    {
        T set = T(Sum);
        firstNumberChecker = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out firstNumber);
        //returnClass.FirstNumber = firstNumberChecker ? input : 0;
        secondNumberChecker = Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out secondNumber);
        //returnClass.SecondNumber = secondNumberChecker ? input : 0;
    }



public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.Compute();
    }

    public int FirstNumber { get; set; }
    public int SecondNumber { get; set; }
    public int ReturnObj { get; set; }

    public abstract void Compute();
}
public class Sum : BaseClass
{
    public override void Compute()
    {
        ReturnObj = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
    }
}

    public class Difference : BaseClass
    {
        public override void Compute()
        {
            ReturnObj = FirstNumber - SecondNumber;
        }
    }
```

It errors at the commented code. I want to set the value of T returnClass so that i can put values to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It errors because although you've specified that `T` is a class, you haven't defined any of the characteristics of the class. However, in your code you are expecting to be able to set `FirstNumber` and `SecondNumber` on instance of T.

One way around this is to define an interface with those properties:

```
interface ISomeNumbers
{
  int FirstNumber{get; set;}
  int SecondNumber{get; set;}
}
```

And then have your types implement the interface. Now, you can specify a generic constraint on the method:

```
private static void InputTwoDegits<T>(out int firstNumber, out int secondNumber, out bool firstNumberChecker, out bool secondNumberChecker, int input, T returnClass) where T : ISomeNumbers
```

Now you'll be able to set the properties as you've told the compiler what you expect to be able to do on instances of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this method to:

```
private static void InputTwoDegits<T>(
    out int firstNumber, 
    out int secondNumber, 
    out bool firstNumberChecker, 
    out bool secondNumberChecker, 
    int input, 
    T returnClass) where T : BaseClass   // <---- constraint on BaseClass instead of Class
```

Also you might change the signature of this method, so it is returning something.

```
public override void Compute()
{
    ReturnObj = FirstNumber + SecondNumber;
}
```